# Overlay Circle Markers on SwiftUI Slider

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, slider

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I'm trying to overlay circle markers on a Slider to represent annotations on a video timeline. However, I'm facing an issue where the circle markers are not appearing on the slider as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentTime: TimeInterval = 0
    @State private var annotations: [Annotation] = [] // Assume you have a struct named Annotation
    
    // Other properties and functions...

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Slider(value: Binding(get: {
                currentTime
            }, set: { newValue in
                // Function to handle slider value change...
            }), in: 0...getTotalDuration(), step: 0.01)
            .accentColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            
            ForEach(annotations) { annotation in
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    .position(x: calculateMarkerPosition(annotation.timestamp))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // Function to handle tap on the circle marker...
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
        // Other UI components...
    }

    // Other functions...
}
```

In this code, I'm attempting to overlay red circle markers on a blue-accented slider, but the circles are not showing up as expected.

Could someone help me understand what might be causing this issue? Is there a better approach to overlaying circle markers on a SwiftUI slider?

Thanks in advance!
image from iOS simulator
[image: image from iOS simulator]

image from xcode layout debugger
[image: image from xcode layout debugger]

Comment: You've put the 2 views in a HStack, and they're appearing one after another horizontally.   Why are you expecting any different behaviour?

Comment: I want to add the dot "Circle" on the slider tracker ?

Comment: if you want to have the red `Circle` on top of the `Slider` knob,
 then try using an `.overlay{Circle()...}` on the `Slider`. Adjust the (x,y) position as required.

Comment: if you please show me in code ?

Comment: `Slider(...) {...}.overlay {
     Circle().foregroundColor(.red)
     .position(x: currentTime ..., y: 16)
 }` . Adjust the (x,y) position as required. Try something that works for you.

Comment: can you convert your comment as Answer you deserve the point

Comment: thanks for the offer. I'm good, as long as you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it using .overlay() on Slider

```
        Slider(value: Binding(get: {
            currentTime
        }, set: { newValue in
            seekToTime(newValue)
        }), in: 0...getTotalDuration(), step: 0.01)
        .overlay(
            ZStack {
                ForEach(annotations, id: \.self) { annotation in
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                        .position(x: calculateMarkerPosition(annotation.timestamp),y: 15)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            jumpToAnnotation(annotation)
                        }
                }
            }
        )
        .accentColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: screen.width)
        }
```

[image]